# what is the command to know when a subversion revision was committed?

Tags: svn, date, datetime

I'm trying to find out when a specific subversion revision was committed. 
What command should I use ?

I use subversion 1.6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When revision N was committed you can always to know with `svn log`

`svn log URL/OF/REPO -r N -l 1 -q`

Answer (score 1):

`$ svn list`

When you execute svn list command with –verbose option it displays the following information:

- Revision number of the last commit
- Author of the last commit
- Size (in bytes)
- Date and time of the last commit

Source: [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/04/svn-command-examples/)

There might be a better one. Hope this helps for now.